# Data Transfer From Table to Table in BigQuery

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, timezone, firebase-analytics, data-transfer

I have a question about BigQuery data. In my events dataset, there is a table for each date, like 20240301, 20240302, and so on. For example, for the table for 20240305, the timestamps are recorded based on the UTC+8 timezone, meaning that the timestamps pulled from this table range from 4:00 PM UTC of the previous day to 4:00 PM UTC of the current day (corresponding to 00:00 - 24:00 in UTC+8 time). Now, what I want is for the timestamps pulled from the table for 20240305 to be based on UTC time for March 5th, from 00:00 to 24:00 UTC time. Is this possible?

Does this mean that I need to shift some data (from 4:00 PM to 12:00 AM) from one table to the previous table? For instance, if the table for March 5th currently contains data from 4:00 PM UTC of March 4th to 4:00 PM UTC of March 5th, then it doesn't have the data we want for March 5th from 4:00 PM to 12:00 AM, which should be in the table for March 6th. How can I move the corresponding data to the correct table? Or is there another method to achieve what I need?

Thank you in advance.